# Join Pyspark Dataframes on substring match

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, substring, left-join

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 somewhat like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from spark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("someAppname").getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"entity_nm": ["Joe B", "Donald", "Barack Obama"]}))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"aliases": ["Joe Biden; Biden Joe", "Donald Trump; Donald J. Trump", "Barack Obama", "Joe Burrow"], "id": [1, 2, 3, 4]}))
```

I want to join df2 on df1 based on a string contains match, it does work when I do it like this:

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, df2.aliases.contains(df1.entity_nm), how="left")
```

That join gives me my desired result:

```
+------------+--------------------+---+
|   entity_nm|             aliases| id|
+------------+--------------------+---+
|       Joe B|Joe Biden; Biden Joe|  1|
|       Joe B|Joe Burrow          |  4|
|      Donald|Donald Trump; Don...|  2|
|Barack Obama|        Barack Obama|  3|
```

**Problem here:** I tried to do this with a list of 60k entity names in df1 and around 6 million aliases in df2 and this approach takes like forever until at some point my Spark session will just crash due to memory errors. I'm pretty sure that my approach is very naive and far from optimized.

I've read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/spark-join-using-regex-40a8589c0354) blog post which suggests to use a udf but I don't have any Scala knowledge and struggle to understand and recreate it in PySpark.

Any suggestions or help on how to optimize my approach? I need to do tasks like this a lot, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The approach desribed in the linked article is based on the idea to broadcast the regexp table (the smaller of the two tables). As the smaller table here has already 60k entries I am not sure if this approach works for this case.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was sort of thinking the same. Actually, after posting I have revised my Spark config and noticed that someone had put spark.driver.maxResultSize = "2g" into it. I deleted that one and my script ran smoothly in under 1 hour haha